# Working with pointer in C: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion

Tags: c

This is the exact error

```
incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'char'
```

This is my code in which I am trying to make str equal to hexarr2 but am unsure how to do so.

```
void int_to_hex(unsigned int x, char *str)
{

  char hexarr2[9] = {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',' '};

  for (j = 0 ;j<9;j++){
    str = hexarr2[j];
    str++;
  }
    
}
```

Comment: What do you not understand about the error message?

Comment: Change `str` to `*str`

Comment: Another way: `str[j] = hexarr2[j];` and remove `str++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to copy the characters from `hexarr2` to `str` the easiest thing to do is:

```
void int_to_hex(unsigned int x, char *str)
  {
  char hexarr2[9] = {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',' '};

  for (j = 0 ; j < sizeof(hexarr2) ; j++)
    str[j] = hexarr2[j];

  str[sizeof(hexarr2)] = '\0';
  }
```

This assumes that the buffer pointed to by `str` is large enough to accomodate all the characters in `hexarr2`.